# I can't get the notifications by i.d after saving it as a many to many field

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have previously figured out how to send and save notifications by many to many fields to send to users, now i can't specifically call the notifications by current user logged in i.d.

***Models.py***

```
class Notifications(models.Model):

 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 sent_to = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
 message = models.TextField(null=True)
 message_reply = models.TextField(null=True)
 created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

*The notifications_sent_to is the created table after I created the many to many save*

[image]

Notifications_sent_to table (which is not created in the models)
[image]

Notifications table (which stores the message)
[image]

***Views.py***

```
def add_notification(request):

notifs = Notifications.objects.all()
users = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=True)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddNotifForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.message_reply = "none"
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        sent_to = form.cleaned_data.get('sent_to')
        messages.success(request, f'Message has been successfully sent .')
        return redirect('add_notif')
else:
    form = AddNotifForm()

context={

    'notifs' : notifs,
    'form' : form,
    'users' : users,
}

template_name ='main-admin/add-notif.html'
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

***Forms.py***

```
class AddNotifForm(forms.ModelForm):

sent_to = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=True).exclude(is_superuser=True),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True)

class Meta: 
    model = Notifications
    fields = ['sent_to', 'message']
```

***Templates view***

```
{% for sent_to_users in sent_to_users %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ sent_to_users.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ sent_to_users.sent_to }}</td>
       <td>{{ sent_to_users.message }}</td>
       <td>
       {% if sent_to_users.message_reply == "none" %}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary reply_open_modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#replyModal">Reply</button>
       {% else %}
       {{ sent_to_users.message_reply }}
       {% endif %}
       </td>
       <td>{{ sent_to_users.created_at }}</td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to get the `Notification` objects where the current user is part of the `sent_to` list?

Comment: Yes, something like that, i want to get all of the notifications that is set with the current user i.d

Comment: Ah in that case, if the current user is `request.user`, then you can do `Notifications.objects.filter(sent_to=request.user)`

Comment: I see, but now the Notifications table in the database has no sent_to column and i has been transferred to the Notifications_sent_to table which it contains notifications_id and CustomUser id

Comment: I have updated the pics so you can see what i'm referring to. thanks

Comment: Yes, that's because django will create an intermediary table automatically for you to link the notifications and the custom user tables

Comment: How can i reference that table now?

Comment: You don't have to, because you can get the related custom users from `Notification`, and you can also get the related notifications from `CustomUser`. But if you really want to handle it yourself, have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on how to do it.

Comment: Your codes worked out fine now, but the sent_to_users.sent_to is not showing the username of the notification reciever

Comment: You have to iterate over it, as `sent_to` here will be a manager. So, `{% for s in sent_to_users.sent_to.all %}`

Comment: It still reflects mainuser.CustomUser.none

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241446/discussion-between-vincent-john-labrador-and-brian-destura).